# Использование SIMD регистров в многопоточном коде

Tags: c++, многопоточность, simd

я запускаю 4 потока в своем коде, каждый поток в определенный момент выполняет функцию, в которой используются 512-битные регистры. Всего есть 32 регистра, а в каждом потоке в функции объявляется 8 переменных типа __m512. Вроде все хорошо, но что если потоков будет 8, как компьютер будет справляться? И все ли правильно в моем рассуждении выше?

Comment: *"все ли правильно в моем рассуждении выше"* - там нет никакого рассуждения, есть только рассказ о том, что у вас есть. Приводите [mcve]

Comment: при переключении потоков процессор сохраняет все регистры, при этом неважно сколько из них вы используете - 1 или все, каждый поток работает со "своей копией" этих регистров.   вот если вы их не будете использовать совсем, то переключение будет чуть быстрее